# How to align div to top right corner of screen regardless of resolution?

Tags: javascript, css

This is in regards to the following page:
http://kinkarso.com/rayku/slider.html

I'm looking to position the box to the top right corner of the screen, but currently if the screen resolution is different, it doesn't stay to the very right. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### No need for javascript, use CSS instead

Set position to fixed and add additional properties:

```
#tutors-popup {

    /* fixed within viewport */
    position: fixed;

    /* set position */
    top: 20px;
    right: 30px;

    /* must have dimension */
    width: 100px;
    height: 200px;
}
```

You will also realise you don't need the inner div...

If you don't like fixed alignment from the right margin, you can set `right` using % dimension as well. This will then set it differently depending on screen width (or resolution you're referring to).

Answer (score 2):

Change the CSS from your Div Container to this

```
#tutors-popup {
   position: fixed;
   top: 0;
   right: 0;
}
```

The div 'tutors-popup' is now in the top right corner even if you change the Resolution.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set a variable width for your `container`, otherwise you won't be able to achieve this I guess. So `width:100%` would do. Then set the actual popup to the top right corner with `float:right`

Note: This is only one solution, there propably are more out there!